# Indoor Positioning System

Tags: wireless-networking, mac

We are developing an indoor positioning system. And for locating the indoor position we are using Wi-Fi, as we know GPS does not work properly inside a building so it was ruled out. As I was going through some of the website  and found that [Wi-Fi positioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system) technique with wireless access points is based on measuring the intensity of the received signal  and the method of "**fingerprinting**".

Since the typical parameters useful to geolocate the Wi-Fi hotspot or wireless access point include the SSID and the MAC address of the access point.

My question here is,

1. If wi-fi is password protected then how device will get the SSID and MAC address of the access point?
2. What is fingerprinting in Wi-Fi positioning system and how it helps in determining the position of a device?

Comment: SSID and MAC are broadcast in the clear by the access point *before* you authenticate to it, in order that you can find it in the first place.

Comment: There are also many resources you can find on Google. E.g. http://www.int-arch-photogramm-remote-sens-spatial-inf-sci.net/XXXVIII-4-C26/1/2012/isprsarchives-XXXVIII-4-C26-1-2012.pdf